# Java Desktop Application (GUI Using Windowsbuilder and Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, desktop-application

I am currently trying to build desktop based application using Java, Eclipse and Windowsbuilder (for the UI).  I am confused as to how to go about doing it. I want the whole application to have only a window, then within the window, depending on user's action it will sort of like go to other 'pages'. I have tried developing android before, thus I know that I can call another activity by using intent. So may I know how to do this on Java desktop based application? Please guide me!

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: I'm a bit unsure if that's what you want, but take a look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply, @kiheru! But what if I want to direct the user's action to another class, where the other 'pages' refers to another UI, but still within the same window? I know it's unclear of what I want, but I am having issues explaining as well. Sorry..

Comment: `CardLayout` can switch between different component contents (the component can be the whole window, if needs be). The first example on the page I linked to does that.

Comment: Hey @kiheru, what I want to implement is like a login system. Like, after a user has logged in successfully, they will be redirected to another UI with different features. But however, I want the same window to be retained.. How do I go about doing things? Will cardlayout work as well? Wouldn't that make the particular class very complicated and messy containing so many components?

Comment: CardLayout can be used for that. You don't need to stuff everything in the same class. Make the login and main UIs separate JComponents (JPanels perhaps), and place those on a window using CardLayout. Then switch the active component when the login component notifies about a successful login. (With that arrangement youd end up with about 3 separate classes: the container (window), login page, and main page; add more granularity if appropriate).